# How to get the values of convolutional layes in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.6

I have the code below from Github Tutorial, and I want to access the values of each "x layer" and save it into numpy array after the training is completed.

```
def decoder(sampled_z, keep_prob):
    with tf.variable_scope("decoder", reuse=None):
        x = tf.layers.dense(sampled_z, units=inputs_decoder, activation=lrelu)
        x = tf.layers.dense(x, units=inputs_decoder * 2 + 1, activation=lrelu)
        x = tf.reshape(x, reshaped_dim)
        x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, 
                                       padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
        x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob)
        x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=1, 
                                       padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
        x = tf.nn.dropout(x, keep_prob)
        x = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(x, filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=1, 
                                       padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
        x = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(x)
        x = tf.layers.dense(x, units=28*28, activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
        img = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28])
    return img
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of whether you have a convolutional or a dense layer, and whether you have finished your training or not, you can access the values of your variables via `session` interface (once you have initialized them).

Consider following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def two_layer_perceptron(x):
    with x.graph.as_default():
        with tf.name_scope('fc'):
            fc = tf.layers.dense(
                     inputs=x, units=2,
                     kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.truncated_normal)
        with tf.name_scope('logits'):
            logits = tf.layers.dense(
                         inputs=fc, units=2,
                         kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.truncated_normal)
    return logits

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 2))
logits = two_layer_perceptron(x)

# define loss, train operation and start training

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    # train here
    # ...
    # sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=...)
    # ...
    # when training is finished, do:
    trainable_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
    vars_vals = sess.run(trainable_vars)
    vars_and_names = [(val, var.name) for val, var in zip(vars_vals, trainable_vars)]


for val, name in vars_and_names:
    print(name, type(val), '\n', val)

# dense/kernel:0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
# [[ 0.23275916  0.7079906 ]
# [-1.0366516   1.9141678 ]]
# dense/bias:0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
# [0. 0.]
# dense_1/kernel:0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
# [[-0.55649596 -1.4910121 ]
# [ 0.54917735  0.39449152]]
# dense_1/bias:0 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 
# [0. 0.]
```

If you want access to specific variables in you network you may add them to collection via `tf.add_to_collection()` and later access them via `tf.get_collection()` OR you can just filter by variable name from the list of all variables (e.g. `[v if 'conv' in v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]`)

Comment: Should I apply this code:
                  trainable_vars = tf.trainable_variables()
                  vars_vals = sess.run(trainable_vars)
                  vars_and_names = [(val, var.name) for val, var in zip(vars_vals, 
                  trainable_vars)]
After the training completed, or while I'm training inside the training loop. 

Also, all the layers in my example have the same name "x", how to access each one individually.

Comment: 1. You can apply this code whenever you want to see the values - during training or after training is completed. 2. Each “x” stores a reference to a variable and when you assign a new variable to this reference you lose the access to previous variable. Without storing the reference you can access them only if you add them to collections or by assigning names and ‘filtering’ the variables you need from all trainable variables as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time and explanation

Comment: If answered your question, please consider pressing on *Accept this answer* button.